# Cursor color in vim terminal OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: bash, vim, terminal, macvim

I want to make the cursor and selected text easier to read in vim (white background, black foreground), so i've done

```
hi Visual guibg=white guifg=black gui=NONE ctermfg=black ctermbg=white cterm=reverse
hi Cursor guibg=white guifg=black gui=NONE ctermfg=black ctermbg=white cterm=reverse
```

which gives me exactly what i want on MacVim. On the vim terminal, however, it defaults to the terminal preferences, which is very difficult to read and find...how can i override the terminal defaults?

**Edit:** to say that the `hi Visual` like works perfectly. It's the `hi Cursor` that doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not a Mac user, but I don't believe this is possible. The cursor colour in console Vim is inherited from the terminal application, and can't be modified.* You could try changing the cursor colour in the terminal preferences.

*Disclaimer: this is certainly true of the Windows command prompt, which I am forced to use at work. It wouldn't surprise me if other Unix-like shells were more flexible.

Comment: Some terminal emulators support control codes for altering the cursor color, but not Mac OS X Terminal (at least as of 10.8).

Comment: Verified this is true of terminal in OSX as of 10.8.2. I wasted some time trying to change the cursor shape to a vertical bar 25% width in insert mode.

Comment: Changing the cursor color is now possible in OS X Mavericks (10.9). Just go to the settings, edit your theme and use the new "Cursor" color picker.

Comment: can it be programmatically set?  or can it only be set in the settings panel?  it would be supercool if i could program the cursor background/foreground in vim for terminal.app

Comment: Up MacOS 10.12.1, Terminal.app can not do this. You can set the style via an escape sequence, but not the color.

Comment: This is still true in macOS Catalina, super annoying!

Answer (score 10):

You can't change the cursor colour programatically (i.e. just do it for vim), but you can change it in Terminal>Preferences>Profiles>Text>Cursor (see image), which may solve your issue.

I find a bright green cursor makes a big difference for visibility!

***EDIT:** This is mentioned in the comments, but I missed that the first time so I think it deserves its own answer.*

[image: Terminal settings]

Comment: that is what I was looking for!